My Gradle project wont run because it says my toolchains
Im using Gradle 8.5 together with JDK 21 but it will only start with languageVersion=17 even though I changed it to 21 in my build.gradle file, changed it to 21 in my IntelliJ Settings for gradle and changed it to 21 in my IntelliJ Settings for the project. My logs look like this:
Execution failed for task ':mcp:setupMCP'.

No matching toolchains found for requested specification: {languageVersion=17, vendor=any, implementation=vendor-specific} for WINDOWS on x86_64.
No locally installed toolchains match and toolchain auto-provisioning is not enabled.

I wanted to make a mod for minecraft using mcp reborn and every time i run etup to set it up it will tell me in the logs Im using Java language version 17 even though ive changed it to 21 in my IntelliJ Settings also for Gradle(which it says when I start the program but when I the error comes up it says languageVersion=17) and i changed the Java version in the build.gradle file:
java.toolchain.languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(21)
If i reload Gradle the reloading works fine but then when I start to setup Gradle wont work

Try to run gradle command in console (terminal) CMD.exe to check your build.gradle , do not run it in the IDE (IDEA , Netbeans...).
